# Boot loop after mixing different speed and model of RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard

Little history and description:

For my birthday I decided to gift myself new RAM. The model is `Crucial Ballistix Black 8GB DDR4-3200 UDIMM CL16 1.35V`. I'm trying to add it in addition to what is currently in the system, `Ballistix Sport LT Red 8GB Single DDR4-2400 UDIMM CL16 1.2V` that was purchased in 2017.

Both memory sticks have the same CAS (CL16), type (DDR4), low-voltage, even the "brand" is the same. The only difference is speed (2400 vs 3200).

Happy I received the package, I installed it according to the manual of my motherboard, `ASUS PRIME B350M-A`, I put the new memory module in slot 1 `-DIMM_A1-` and old one in slot 3 `-DIMM_B1-`, unfortunately when I turned on the PC it started to make a loop without showing anything on the screen.

I'm writing this using only my original RAM. I tried changing the memory positions, to slot 2 and slot 4, same result. I even tried ,without success, to put them in slot 1 and slot 2.

I would like to know, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be.

Comment: You're mixing 1.2V and 1.35V, which is ill advised.